# Azure pipeline trigger from another repo and branch not working

Tags: azure-pipelines

My aim is to trigger a pipeline in a different repo, from another repo where the branch get's updated. However I can't get it working.

I was trying this:

```
# Do not trigger for this repo
trigger: none

# Only trigger when "trigger-tests" is updated in other repo
resources:
    - repository: other
      type: git
      name: Project/Repository
      ref: trigger-tests
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - trigger-tests
```

The other repo is in the same DevOps project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the build can run manually first. It seems you missed `repositories` in your syntax. Check the following sample, which works on my side:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: other
    type: git
    name: Project/Repository
    ref: master
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master
```

In addition, if the issue persists, please create a new pipeline and have another try.

Comment: Will test on Monday. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. Will post the results in the answer.

Comment: When you run the pipeline manually, are you able to see repo `DevOps` and `test_repo` are downloaded?

Comment: Yes the pipeline runs manually. And I can see DevOps/test_repo are listed under the pipeline Sources. Seems only the trigger from another repo is not working.

Comment: See the answer above, I've simplified it more, still not working...

Comment: When you create a new pipeline, did you create the pipeline under master branch?

Comment: No, it would have been under another test branch I created, separate to "trigger-tests".

Comment: Try to go to pipeline -- New pipeline -- Azure Repos Git -- select repo -- Starter pipeline, and paste the yaml file there, to see how's the result.

Comment: Still not working. I create a new pipeline (as below) and save it under a "azure-pipeline-test" branch. Then I update the readme in "DevOps/test_repo" master branch. The pipeline is not triggered.

Comment: Wired issue.. Could you please try to capture the fiddler trace when you update the readme in "DevOps/test_repo" master branch, to see whether there is any trigger information or any useful information? In addition, could you please try in another team project to see whether you have the same issue?

Comment: I was able to get this working by creating a new branch and a new repo. It seems it doesn't work with existing branches where the pipeline would live, and existing repo's I want to trigger off.

That would seem pointless... Possibly a bug?

Comment: I don't think so. I tested in an existing repo and created a new pipeline, the trigger worked as expected. I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my side. You may compare the fiddler trace to check whether there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the pipeline even more:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: other
      type: git
      name: DevOps/test_repo
      ref: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - master

jobs:
- job: One
  steps:
  - script: echo Hello!
```

It's still not triggering when I update DevOps/test_repo master branch